# UIButton like blink

Tags: iphone

hello friend how to make uibutton like blink i have use bellow code but it is not like blink
in my app i am developed recording so i want to like that button

```
CABasicAnimation *pulseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
pulseAnimation.duration = .5;
pulseAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1];
pulseAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
pulseAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
[btnBlink.layer addAnimation:pulseAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can increase or decrease button alpha continuesly using NSTimerInteval by calling a defined method

Comment: This would work,.. You can also change the image in the method you call after each time interval..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/frowing/UIView-blink) little category that will handle it for you.

```
 [self.button blinkWithDuration:0.5f 
                          speed:(NSTimeInterval)0.2f 
                 completionBlock: ^{
    self.button.hidden = YES;
  }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nikki: you not need to animation for blink button, just you need to two images e.g- like active(with have shine) and deactive(without any shine) mode image . set it on button event.its look like a blink :)